# Scrollable div : how to detect scroll direction from OnScroll event for a scrollable div?

Tags: html, scrollbar

How to detect the scroll direction for a scrollable div , From OnScroll event? I want to add 15 to scrollTop, if user scrolls up and subtract 15, if user scrolls down. Is it possible with out using JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/GM3bS/)

```
/**
 * Calculate incremental amounts of pixels scrolled in each axis.
 * Value is signed to its direction.
 */
function incrementalScroll(e) {

    var scrollX = (this.x || window.pageXOffset) - window.pageXOffset;
    var scrollY = (this.y || window.pageYOffset) - window.pageYOffset;

    this.x = window.pageXOffset;
    this.y = window.pageYOffset;

    test(scrollX, scrollY);
}

window.onscroll = incrementalScroll;
```

Use it as you want.

```
function test(scrollX, scrollY){

    var directionX = !scrollX ? "NONE" : scrollX>0 ? "LEFT" : "RIGHT";
    var directionY = !scrollY ? "NONE" : scrollY>0 ? "UP" : "DOWN";

    console.log(directionX, scrollX, directionY, scrollY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is the following. It would be nice if you could wrap `let oldScroll` into a closure to make it cleaner, but it's not necessary.

```
const scrollableEle = document.getElementById('scrollable-ele')
let oldScroll = scrollableEle.scrollTop

scrollableEle.addEventListener('scroll', doSomething)

function doSomething(e) {
  contentRight.scrollTop > oldScroll ? /* down */ : /* up */
  oldScroll = scrollableEle.scrollTop
}
```